# Why is the infinite norm of state vectors in QFT a result of an infinite spacetime volume?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

A somewhat confusing aspect of qft is that the particle states we usually work with,
$$|{1_{\vec{k}}} \rangle\equiv a^\dagger(\vec{k})  |0 \rangle, $$
are not normalizable since
$$  \langle{1_{\vec{k}}|1_{\vec{k}'}}\rangle = (2 \pi)^3  \delta(\vec k-\vec k') .$$
In particular, we have
$$  \langle{1_{\vec{k}}|1_{\vec{k}'}}\rangle = (2 \pi)^3  \delta(0) \, .$$
This, of course, doesn't look very promising. In almost all QFT textbooks with little to no further motivation it is argued that these factors $\delta(0)$ (that also appear, for example, in our scattering amplitudes) are a result of the fact that we work with an infinite spacetime volume. Formulated differently, $\langle{1_{\vec{k}}|1_{\vec{k}'}}\rangle \propto \delta(0)$ is an infrared divergence. By introducing a finite spacetime volume $V$ and using an integral representation of $\delta(x)$ all occurrences of $\delta(0)$ are replaced by $V$. This way the divergences are cancelled out.

- Is there any way to motivate (beyond the formal statement using an integral representation of $\delta(x)$) why the norm of our states should be related to the spacetime volume $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentum eigenstates are non-normalizable in QFT for precisely the same reason that they are non-normalizable in regular old nonrelativistic quantum mechanics - they are pure plane waves which fill the entire space.

Integrating $|e^{ikx}|^2=1$ across all of space yields the volume of the space. I’m not sure to what extent this needs to be *motivated*, insofar as it is pretty clear once you have a handle on what one particle states actually are. Explicitly,

$$\langle k|k\rangle = \int dx \ \langle k|x\rangle\langle x|k\rangle = \int dx \ e^{-ikx} e^{ikx}$$
$$=\int dx = V$$